# View doesn't updates but scope element does

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this code which is called from the server and receive an object - I do this using signlr and it does enter into this function.
The view consist of 3 tabs and based on the status it should switch the object from one tab to another.

edited:
each tab contains this html list

```
 <ul class="list-group conv_container_base" id="TodayOrder">
     <li class="list-group-item" ng-class="{ active : $first}" id="{{order.ID}}" ng-repeat="order in todays | filter: searchval | orderBy: TimeOfPickup">
         <a href="#/conv/{{order.ID}}">
         {{order.Client_Name}} - {{order.ID}} {{order.Status}}
         <h5>{{order.TimeOfPickup | netDate}}</h5>
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

padding, pickup and todays are the names of the lists in the scope containing the items.

```
$scope.$parent.$on("updateStatusRecive", function(e, order) {
$scope.$apply(function() {
    if (order.Status == 1) {
        var orders = $scope.padding;
        $scope.padding = [];
        angular.forEach(orders, function(ord) {
            if (ord.ID != order.ID) {
                $scope.padding.push(ord);
            }
        });

        $scope.pickup.push(order);
    } else if (order.Status == 2) {
        var orders = $scope.pickup;
        $scope.pickup = [];
        angular.forEach(orders, function(ord) {
            if (ord.ID != order.ID) { //move to the next one
                $scope.pickup.push(ord);
            }
        });

        $scope.todays.push(order);
    }
});
});
```

I tried to print out the loops to see what happen, it does change the objects but not the view. I don't have any errors in the console.
What can cause this?

Comment: It would be helpful to have more information. What is $scope.todays? Where is that defined/coming from. And the source that calls updateStatusReceive would be useful too. Hard to make any calls with just this. Edit: There is also probably a better way you should be doing this, need to know more info though.

Comment: And please include the HTML that uses `todays`. Are you sure your view is within your ng-controller? Also, do you have any error in the developper console?

Comment: I have edit the question to include html example from the code. all the lists (todays, padding, pickup) initializing at the first load from the server: $http.get('/Order/TodayOrdersJson').success(function (data) {
        $scope.todays = data.Todays;
        $scope.padding = data.PaddingOrders;
        $scope.pickup = data.PaddingPickup;
    });